# SQL Query - MS SCCM

Tags: sql, reportbuilder, sccm

I´m trying to make a report in MS SCCM where I can check the distribution status of Software XY. Now there can be more parts of one software installed (for example XYa, XYb....) but I only want to list the pc once in my report. 
I tried this adding the keyword distinct but nothing changes. Can you help me?

Here´s my query:

```html
select distinct SMS_R_System.Name0,__System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS0.DisplayName00,__System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS0.Version00 from vSMS_R_System AS SMS_R_System INNER JOIN Add_Remove_Programs_DATA AS __System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS0 ON __System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS0.MachineID = SMS_R_System.ItemKey  INNER JOIN _RES_COLL_SMS00001 AS SMS_CM_RES_COLL_SMS00001 ON SMS_CM_RES_COLL_SMS00001.MachineID = SMS_R_System.ItemKey   where __System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS0.DisplayName00 like N'%XY%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll get a row returned for each different application name and version because you're including DisplayName00 and Version00 in your SELECT statement. If you just have the system name in the SELECT then the distinct will work as intended.